# Cannot run android project because https://jcenter.bintray.com/ is down

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, bintray, jcenter

[image][image]

Hello today i want to run android project but getting error like this, anyone know how to solve this issue, i check https://jcenter.bintray.com/ is down (403), is anyone face same issue with me ? please reply if you know how to fix this, thanks

Comment: jcenter is probably not down. HTTP status code 403 means "Forbidden", so they revoked your access rights, or they require authorization headers. I also ran into that problem with jcenter recently, when I had to test a build tool that would repeatedly access their servers and cause 404 errors. My guess is they temporarily ban IP addresses for too many or bad requests. You could try switching to `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()` in your repositories configuration. Not sure if all Android libraries are also published there, but it's worth a shot

Comment: i am already try switching from jcenter() to mavenCentral() but still got the error

Comment: Use the google() repo to download the google play services libraries